# Is it grammatical/common to put "are" after the subject in questions?

Tags: grammar, word-order, questions, interrogatives, colloquial-language

Example:

> Which one are we watching?
>
> Which one we're watching?

Is it common to do this? Sometimes I see it, but many native English speakers tell me that I should add the *are*.

Comment: You've not omitted anything.  "We're" is short for "we are".  Effectively, the word "are" occurs in both sentences.  But no, if it's a complete sentence, it has to be "are we".  ("Which one we're watching" would work as part of a sentence - "I don't know which one we're watching" - or as the response to the question, "What would you like to know?".)

Comment: @rjpond You're right. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Which one are we watching?" is a question.  "Which one we're watching" is an incomplete sentence (a noun phrase, I believe).

"I don't know which one we're watching" would be a complete question.

[More information on how to form questions in English](https://www.espressoenglish.net/an-easy-way-to-form-almost-any-question-in-english/).  The auxiliary "to be" verb is required, one way or another.